# Expression to capture first slash in middle of line and one at end

Tags: regex, sed

Trying to write a regular expression that will capture only the first forward slash, and the last slash at the end of a line.

e.g.

```
bryan / /Desktop/CW_Archive/
      ^                    ^
    match                match

bryan / /Desktop/updates.txt
      ^
    match
```

I am new to regex, but so far I have `(?=\/)(.*?)(?<=\/)` -- but this is matching all slashes.

Comment: What regex flavor / programming language are you using?

Comment: BRE? with `sed`

Comment: So you just want to capture two slashes? Why do you need a such a complicated solution? Just use slashes, no effort.

Answer (score 0):

With BRE, you'd use `/\/.*\/$` -- a slash, some characters, then a slash as the last character.

A demo (using alternate delimiters for the `s` command):

```
sed 's!/.*/$!x!' <<END
bryan / /Desktop/CW_Archive/
bryan / /Desktop/updates.txt
END
```

```
bryan x
bryan / /Desktop/updates.txt
```

Comment: This captures everything between the slashes. I wanted to capture the slashes themselves. More along the lines of `\/$` ...for end of line and a simple `\/` with no `/g` to capture first...I just don't know how to join the two

Comment: Please edit your question to show your expected output. I don't know what you want.